# Passing command line arguments to C# projects, from devenv, while building a vdproj

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, installation

We have a vdproj (Visual Studio Setup File) which references and builds some C# projects. In our build system, we would like to override some properties in the C# projects, when the vdproj gets built. Is there any way to do achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a new configuration, like "Release (Setup)", and have your installer build with that configuration.